# How can I get a request value of slim framework?

Tags: php, slim

I'm working with slim framework:

This is my code:

```
$app->post($sPathApi.$sVersion.'subirarchivo', function () use ($app) {
    session_cache_limiter(false);
    session_start();
    if(isset($_SESSION['admin'])){
        require "controller/controllerExcel.php";
        $request = $app->request();
        $body = $request->getBody();
        print_r($request);
        //print_r($body->env['slim.request.form_hash']);
        exit();
        $aInput = json_decode($body); 
        $aGuardar = new ControllerExcel();
        header('Content-Type: application/json');
        echo json_encode($aGuardar->setDataExcel());
        exit();
    }
```

});

I use `print_r($request);`

And I print this:

[image]

How can I get the value of `['request']`?. In the image is marked with red.

Sorry by my english.

Answer (score 1):

You should use

```
echo $this->env['slim.request.form_hash']
```

You can also access env by

```
echo  $app['environment']['slim.request.form_hash'];
```

Also check

http://docs.slimframework.com/environment/overview/#environment-variables